# Full working example of react-native-side-menu with routes or navigation

Tags: menu, routes, navigation, react-native

I found few posts that give some "hints" on how to integrate navigation\routes with react-native-side-menu, unfortunately didn't find any post that show full working example of such functionality.

I'm also not sure what is the simplest implementation for navigation\routes, and what's the difference between these 2 options (of course this is not specifically to side menu, but in my case should join together).

Can any one point to such example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So eventually I was able to integrate standard Navigator as demonstrated in Facebook's official sample code:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator

With react-native-side-menu component, and this is how the entire code looks like:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var SideMenu = require('react-native-side-menu');

var {
  Component,
  Navigator,
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity
} = ReactNative;

class FirstPage extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.page}><Text style={styles.pageContent}>First Page</Text></View>
      );    
  }
}

class FirstPageMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
          isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
        });
    }

    updateMenuState(isOpen) {
        this.setState({ isOpen, });
    }

    onMenuItemSelected = (item) => {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: false,      
            selectedItem: item,
        });
        this.props.navigator.replace({ id: item });
    }

    render() {

        const menu = <Menu onItemSelected={this.onMenuItemSelected} navigator={this.props.navigator}/>;

        return (
            <SideMenu
              menu={menu}
              isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
              onChange={(isOpen) => this.updateMenuState(isOpen)}>
                <MenuButton onPress={() => this.toggle()}/>
                <FirstPage/>
            </SideMenu>                
        );
    }
};

class SecondPage extends Component {
     ...
}

class SecondPageMenu extends Component {
     ...
}

class ThirdPage extends Component {
     ...
}

class ThirdPageMenu extends Component {
     ...
}

class MenuNavigator extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._setNavigatorRef = this._setNavigatorRef.bind(this);
  }

  renderScene(route, nav) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'first':
        return <FirstPageMenu navigator={nav} />;
      case 'second':
        return <SecondPageMenu navigator={nav} />;
      case 'third':
        return <ThirdPageMenu navigator={nav} />;
      default:
        return <FirstPageMenu navigator={nav} />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        ref={this._setNavigatorRef}
        initialRoute={{id: 'first'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={(route) => {
          if (route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom;
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._listeners && this._listeners.forEach(listener => listener.remove());
  }

  _setNavigatorRef(navigator) {
    if (navigator !== this._navigator) {
      this._navigator = navigator;

      if (navigator) {
        var callback = (event) => {
          console.log(
            `NavigatorMenu: event ${event.type}`,
            {
              route: JSON.stringify(event.data.route),
              target: event.target,
              type: event.type,
            }
          );
        };
        // Observe focus change events from the owner.
        this._listeners = [
          navigator.navigationContext.addListener('willfocus', callback),
          navigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus', callback),
        ];
      }
    }
  }
};

class MenuButton extends Component {

  handlePress(e) {
    if (this.props.onPress) {
      this.props.onPress(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.menuButton} >
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}
          style={this.props.style}>
          <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/vKRaKDX.png', width: 40, height: 40, }} />        
        </TouchableOpacity>      
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    onItemSelected: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <ScrollView scrollsToTop={false} style={styles.menu}>

        <Text
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected('first')}
          style={styles.item}>
          First
        </Text>

        <Text
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected('second')}
          style={styles.item}>
          Second
        </Text>

        <Text
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected('third')}
          style={styles.item}>
          Third
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    menuButton: {
        marginTop: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#777'
    },
    menu: {
      flex: 1,
      width: window.width,
      height: window.height,
      padding: 20,
    },
    item: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '300',
      paddingTop: 20,
    },    
    page: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#777'
    },
    pageContent: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        top: 200,
    },
    menu: {
      flex: 1,
      width: window.width,
      height: window.height,
      padding: 20,
    },
    item: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '300',
      paddingTop: 20,
  },   
});

module.exports = MenuNavigator;
```

And index file should just point to Navigator:

```
const React = require('react-native');
const { AppRegistry, } = React;
const MenuNavigator = require('./SideMenuWithNavigation');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MenuNavigator);
```

Comment: a bit tricky but working! thanks!

Comment: I want to show alert on the click of logout icon in side menu. Is it possible in this code?

Comment: instead of this.props.onItemSelected you can call any other method you want for onPress event of some specific items in the menu

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the drawer menu, check react-native-material-design and the given demo-app.

Comment: I'm talking about this component: https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-side-menu

Answer (score 1):

### I have a starter on my Github with `react-native-side-menu` and `navigator`.

> This starter also use redux (*won't prevent from answering how to deal navigator + side menu*).

**When using sidemenu, the `trick` for `routing` is to replace previous route to prevent it from stacking (like it should in a common navigation):**

```
  navigate(route) {
    const routeStack      = [].concat(this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes());
    const previousRouteId = routeStack[routeStack.length - 1].id;
    if (route.id !== previousRouteId) {
      this.refs.navigator.replace(route);
    }

    if (this.state.sideMenuOpened) {
      this.closeSideMenu();
    }
  }
```

**Check my starter [reactNativeReduxFastStarter](https://github.com/MacKentoch/reactNativeReduxFastStarter/blob/master/ReactNativeApp/ios/container/app/App.js)**

**fast preview of code:**

```
import React, {
  Component
}                           from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  Navigator,
  StatusBar
}                           from 'react-native';
import SideMenu             from 'react-native-side-menu';
import Icon                 from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { AppRoutes }        from '../../../common/config';
import {
  SideMenuContent,
  Button
}                           from '../../components';
import Home                 from '../home';
import AppState             from '../appState';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.state = {
      sideMenuOpened: false
    };
  }

  openSideMenu() {
    this.setState({
      sideMenuOpened : false
    });
  }

  closeSideMenu() {
    if (this.state.sideMenuOpened) {
      this.setState({
        sideMenuOpened : false
      });
    }
  }

  toggleSideMenu() {
    this.setState({
      sideMenuOpened: !this.state.sideMenuOpened
    });
  }

  updateSideMenuState(isOpened) {
    this.setState({
      sideMenuOpened: isOpened
    });
  }

  navigate(route) {
    const routeStack      = [].concat(this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes());
    const previousRouteId = routeStack[routeStack.length - 1].id;
    if (route.id !== previousRouteId) {
      this.refs.navigator.replace(route);
    }

    if (this.state.sideMenuOpened) {
      this.closeSideMenu();
    }
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
    case 1:
      const route1 = AppRoutes.getRouteFromRouteId(1);
      return (
        <Home
          ref={route1.refView}
          navigator={navigator}
          navigate={(toRoute)=>this.navigate(toRoute)}
        />
      );
    case 2:
      const route2 = AppRoutes.getRouteFromRouteId(2);
      return (
        <AppState
          ref={route2.refView}
          navigator={navigator}
          navigate={(toRoute)=>this.navigate(toRoute)}
        />
      );
    default:
      return (
        <Home
          ref={route1.refView}
          navigator={navigator}
          navigate={(toRoute)=>this.navigate(toRoute)}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  renderRouteMapper() {
    const routes = AppRoutes.getAllRoutes();
    return  {
      Title : (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        const currentRouteId  = navState.routeStack[index].id;
        return (
          <Text style={styles.titleNavText}>
            {routes[currentRouteId - 1].navbar.navBarTitle}
          </Text>
        );
      },
      LeftButton : (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        const currentRouteId  = navState.routeStack[index].id;
        return (
          <Button
            style={styles.leftNavButton}
            onPress={(e)=>this.toggleSideMenu(e)
            }>
            <Icon
              name={routes[currentRouteId - 1].navbar.navBarLeftIconName}
              size={32}
              color={'#333333'}
            />
          </Button>
        );
      },
      RightButton : (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        return null;
      }
    };

  }

  render() {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);
    const DEFAULT_ROUTE = { id: 1, refView: 'HomeView' };

    return (
      <SideMenu
        menu={<SideMenuContent
                backGndColor="#ECECEC"
                navigate={(route)=>this.navigate(route)}
              />}
        isOpen={this.state.sideMenuOpened}
        onChange={(isOpened) => this.updateSideMenuState(isOpened)}
        bounceBackOnOverdraw={false}
        openMenuOffset={SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.8}
        >
        <Navigator
          ref="navigator"
          initialRoute={ DEFAULT_ROUTE }
          sceneStyle={ styles.navigator }
          renderScene={(route, navigator)=>this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
          configureScene={()=>Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              routeMapper={this.renderRouteMapper()}
              style={styles.navBar}
            />
          }
        />
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navigator: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderLeftWidth: 0.5,
    borderLeftColor: '#F1F1F1',
  },
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth:      0.5,
    borderColor:    '#F1F1F1'
  },
  leftNavButton : {
    flex            : 1,
    flexDirection   : 'column',
    alignItems      : 'center',
    marginTop       : 4,
    paddingTop      : 0,
    paddingBottom   : 10,
    paddingLeft     : 20,
    paddingRight    : 10
  },
  rightNavButton : {
    flex            : 1,
    flexDirection   : 'column',
    alignItems      : 'center',
    marginTop       : 4,
    paddingTop      : 6,
    paddingBottom   : 10,
    paddingLeft     : 10,
    paddingRight    : 10
  },
  titleNavText : {
    marginTop   : 14,
    color       : '#333333'
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this complete sidemenu project on github. This project contains ToolbarAndroid, routes, DrawerLayoutAndroid, overflow menu and other components.

https://github.com/darde/react-native-sidemenu